# Android handle deprecated method

Tags: android

This is how I handle a deprecated method:

```
int layoutDirection ;
if (getContext().getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    layoutDirection = getLayoutDirection();
}else {
    layoutDirection = getResolvedLayoutDirection();
}
```

The problem is that `getResolvedLayoutDirection()` has been removed at JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and above. So since my project targets API 20 the method cannot be found and I get an error.

If I keep it foolish:

```
int layoutDirection = getLayoutDirection();
```

The project compiles and runs but still I get an error to add either the TargetApi or SuppressLint annotation. getLayoutDirection() docs have:

> For compatibility, this will return {@link #LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR} if
>   API version is lower than {@link
>   android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#JELLY_BEAN_MR1}.

So suppressing lint should be fine.

---

Should I suppress the lint error or fix it somehow else (possibly make getResolvedLayoutDirection() accessible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach to conditionally check whether a method is available is to check the version of Android that the device is running, via `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    layoutDirection = getLayoutDirection();
}
else {
    layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR;
}
```

And add `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)` to the method containing the above block to indicate to the build tools that, for that individual method, to consider your `minSdkVersion` to be 17 instead of whatever it normally is, for the purposes of generating Lint warnings and errors.